# Transferring NetBeans IDE for Windows to NetBeans IDE for an Ubuntu based distro

Tags: netbeans

I'm not exactly using Ubuntu but I am using Elementary OS Luna 0.2, which is based on Ubuntu so I'm hoping the same instructions can be applied.

I want to start using Luna as my primary OS and move away from Windows. Luna is installed on the hard drive because I wanted the OS to have the freedom to use all or most system resources to function at optimal efficiency, instead of having to share resources like you would with visualization software. As such I can't easily switch between OSes.

I've been learning Java from home-and-learn and I use NetBeans IDE to construct and compile code for the exercises given(For Loops, Array, etc). Project folders are created for each new exercise and they come in handy for when I need to look back and refresh my memory. I would like to transfer my NetBeans folders from Windows to NetBeans for Linux. So here are my questions.

1. Can I use a USB flash drive or cloud storage to transfer the folders from Windows to Linux and keep the integrity of the data?
2. Where in Luna should I place the folders so that my projects show up in the NetBeans IDE app?
3. Can this data transfer be done through the command line?

**Windows is stored on the OS partition and Luna is stored on the Data partition**

Thanks in advance for the help, however helpful.
Sorry if this was asked before.
Sorry for the typos.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use a USB flash drive or cloud storage to transfer the folders from Windows to Linux and keep the integrity of the data?

Yes you can:

- format USB with FAT32 because is windows GNU/Linux compatible
- copy into your `home/your-user-name/netbeansprj` linux directory
- [convert the EOLs from win to GNU/Linux](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/how-to-convert-windowsdos-text-files-to-linuxunix-format/)
- use `chmod` to change your file bit mode to `-rw-r--r--` for files and `drwxr-xr-x` for directories

> Where in Luna should I place the folders so that my projects show up in the NetBeans IDE app?

Wherever you like:

- for examplein `home/your-user-name/netbeansprj`
- than in Netbeans choose `File > Open project...` and navigate to `home/your-user-name/netbeansprj`
- finally select your project folder

> Can this data transfer be done through the command line?

Not necessarily.